# Declaring variables in UserForm and using them in class module

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a counter `NumObjects` that I declare in UserForm1 which holds the number of labels added to the Userform.

When the Command Button Add Horizontal Table is clicked, the program calls a sub within the class module to add a label to the Userform.

The first table added has the caption "TEACHER" written on it; after this I want the labels to read 1, 2, 3....

So I tried using the counter `NumObjects` in the class module sub in the following statement: `Lbl.Caption = (NumObjects - 1)` but it complains `NumObjects` has not been defined.

How do I get the class module to realize the NumObjects variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumObjects` must be a public variable in the userform and you must prefix it with the userform name when using it elsewhere:

```
Lbl.Caption = (UserformName.NumObjects - 1)
```